# How to select particular text from a variable in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Can anybody help me in pasting the specific text from a variable to "B" column of an Excel sheet using VBA. I have the below code and my code is overriding the text value.

```
Sub OpenFilesInSubFolders(fsoPFolder As Scripting.Folder)
Dim fsoSFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim fileDoc As Scripting.File
Dim wrdRng As Object
Dim strText As String

For Each fsoSFolder In fsoPFolder.SubFolders
    For Each fileDoc In fsoSFolder.Files

        If fileDoc.Name Like FileToOpenVdocx Then
            Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(fileDoc.Path)
            Set wrdRng = wrdDoc.Content

            If wrdRng.Find.Execute(FindText:="Application ID:[0-9]{1,}", MatchWildcards:=True) = True Then
                MsgBox "Text not found!", vbExclamation
            End If
            strText = wrdRng.Text

            Range("B2").Value = strText

            With wrdApp
               .ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Select
               .Selection.Copy
               ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count,  "D").End(xlUp)(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
           End With
           wrdDoc.Close False

    Next fileDoc
    'Debug.Print fsoSFolder

    OpenFilesInSubFolders fsoSFolder
Next fsoSFolder
End Sub
```

Comment: IMO an `End If` is missing! ;).

Comment: Bond, the issue is I am getting the value overriden in B2 column.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, your issue is that you never change the cell you paste to, so for each iteration of the loop, you are simply over-writing whatever was last pasted.

You can add a simple counter so that it pastes the next value below the previous.

```
Sub OpenFilesInSubFolders(fsoPFolder As Scripting.Folder)
Dim fsoSFolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim fileDoc As Scripting.File
Dim wrdRng As Object
Dim strText As String
Dim outRow as Long

outRow = 2 'you appear to want to start at the second row

For Each fsoSFolder In fsoPFolder.SubFolders
    For Each fileDoc In fsoSFolder.Files

        If fileDoc.Name Like FileToOpenVdocx Then
            Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(fileDoc.Path)
            Set wrdRng = wrdDoc.Content

            If wrdRng.Find.Execute(FindText:="Application ID:[0-9]{1,}", MatchWildcards:=True) = True Then
                MsgBox "Text not found!", vbExclamation
            End If
            strText = wrdRng.Text

            Cells(outRow & "B").Value = strText
            outRow = outRow + 1

            With wrdApp
               .ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Select
               .Selection.Copy
               ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count,  "D").End(xlUp)(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
           End With
           wrdDoc.Close False
        End If
    Next fileDoc
    'Debug.Print fsoSFolder

    OpenFilesInSubFolders fsoSFolder
Next fsoSFolder
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi CBRF23,
I am getting "runtime error '1004': Application defined or object -defined error" when I use above outrow & Cells(outRow & "B").Value = strText 

outRow = outRow + 1

Comment: Try changing `Cells` to `Activewokbook.cells`. If that doesn't fix it, try changing `(outrow & "B")` to `(outrow, 2)`.